# Recover my lost data

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, recovery, data-recovery

I wanted to delete my Linux partition, but I don't know why my OS X partition was also deleted.

So, I then reformatted the partition and installed a new OS X (Yosemite) on that partition.

I am trying to recover my lost data, I tried many applications such as Disk Drill, EaseUs, etc. But none of them was able to recover a single file from my 300 GB SSD!

Comment: No Time Machine backup?

Comment: You might have been OK up to the 'installed new OS X' That was probably your downfall, unfortunately.

Comment: There is no way to recover the data :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you hadn't written to it, you might have had a chance.  No chance, now.  Restore from your backup.